# Laravel mix __webpack_require__

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack, laravel-mix

I'm using Laravel 5.8
I'm working on a SPA with VueJs,

Problem with some dependency

here is the error while open some page

[image]
[image]

My `package.json` dependency is

```
"dependencies": {
       "@riophae/vue-treeselect": "^0.2.0",
        "axios": "^0.18",
        "buefy": "^0.7.8",
        "bulma": "^0.7.5",
        "vee-validate": "^2.2.11",
        "vue": "^2.5.17",
        "vue-awesome-swiper": "^3.1.3",
        "vue-router": "^3.1.3"
}
```

My `package.json` devDependency is

```
devDependencies:
"browser-sync": "^2.26.7",
"cross-env": "^5.2.0",
"laravel-mix": "^4.0.7",
"sass": "^1.22.7",
"sass-loader": "7.*",
"vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
```

I guess some issue with these `vue-treeselect` and `vue-awesome-swiper` some time it is working fine but some time show error

My `webpack.mix.js`

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.browserSync({
    proxy: 'localhost:8000'
})

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

mix.webpackConfig({
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources'),
        },
    },
    output: {
        publicPath: '/',
        chunkFilename: 'js/[name].[chunkhash].js',
    },
});
```

Here is how i import vue-swiper

```
import { swiper, swiperSlide } from 'vue-awesome-swiper'
import 'swiper/dist/css/swiper.css'
```

Import vue-treeselect

```
import Treeselect from '@riophae/vue-treeselect'
import '@riophae/vue-treeselect/dist/vue-treeselect.css'
```

Comment: Did you pull in the dependencies with `npm install`?

Comment: yes I did many times @jeremykenedy

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
'@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources'),
```

With:

```
'~': path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/js'),
```

And Update:

```
import Treeselect from '@riophae/vue-treeselect'
```

With:

```
import { Treeselect } from '@riophae/vue-treeselect'
```

Comment: already did it only issue with these `vue-treeselect` and `vue-awesome-swiper` two dependency

Comment: Did you install them to the `devDependencies` list?

Comment: how are you importing those components? What does the import line look like? (e.g. `import Treeselect from '@riophae/vue-treeselect'`)